# Hibernate Validator @URL don't accept URLs without schema

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

If I annotate field with `@URL`:

```
@URL
private String myUrl;
```

and try to set value to it without schema (`google.com` instead `http://google.com`)

then it will throw `ConstraintViolationException`.

How I can let to accept URLs without schema?

Answer (score 4):

As part of the validation routine in `UrlValidator` a `java.net.URL` object with the given value is instantiated. Its constructor doesn't except URLs without protocols, thus the constraint is considered invalid. If you want to accept URLs without protocols, you could either use a regular expression via `@Pattern` or create a custom validator for the `@Url` constraint providing the logic you need.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember you can use that annotation on getter - inside that method you can specify that schema should be added if it's not present already. You can even go as far as creating virtual property getter:

```
String getMyUrl() {
    return myUrl;
}

@URL
String getMyUrlWithSchema() {
    return (myUrl != null &&
               !myUrl.startsWith("http://") &&
               !myUrl.startsWith("https://")) ?
           "http://" + myUrl :
           myUrl;   
}
```

Alternatively you can write your [own validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html).